# BIRT Chart Engine not working

Tags: eclipse, birt

Im new to SWT and need to plot graphs and have chosen to use the BIRT Chart Engine framework, now I've read up online and I think I have installed the BIRT Framework by doing the following in Eclipse:

Help->Install New Software

I then copy the following link in the Work With box: http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.2

It then installed everything - So i would have assumed. Now I would like to start developing but for some reason I can't import that packages eg import org.eclipse.birt.*; to start developing. Please any help to get me plotting graphs would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the following:

Right-click your project ➡ Properties ➡ Java Build Path ➡ Libraries and confirm that the Birt library is contained in this list.

If not, add it by clicking on "Add library".